# Reduce the chances of getting errors in a huge system

Tags: git, codeigniter

I have an online system which sell games for lottery. 
The system create contests, generate games (for a sort of different lotteries), manage results, verify these results, register clients, manage credits and create reports.

It got really big and complex. The system is running and working but I still upgrading.

Since everything is entangled, every little change may cause a catastrophe. As the system grows so does its entropy.

I try to reduce the chances of errors by testing, but almost every time I miss something. This is bringing me trouble lately.

What can I do to reduce the chances of error in a big system like this one?

OBS:

- Yes, I use Git.
- I use Codeigniter (mine is hmvc).
- Is this the properly place to ask this or should I ask in another StackExchange?

Comment: How many unit tests do you have?

Comment: Manual testing is a misnomer.  I like to call that "exploration."  You need automated tests, especially unit tests.

Comment: @X3074861X I don't use unit tests actually. Interesting idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any major system that's doing a lot of complex tasks, [unit tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) and [integration tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing) are going to be your best friend. You should have two projects within your solution that are built specially for this purpose - one for unit tests, and one for integration tests.

While it may seem boring or tedious to do, a well written unit or integration test can easily save you from deploying broken code - typically you'll have a group of tests that are run prior to deployment, and if any one of those should fail, the deployment is halted way before anything goes out to production.

This also brings up the topic of [code coverage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage), meaning basically, how much of your code is testable? Do you have a test to represent every unit of work your application performs? These are questions you need to ask as you're writing your tests. Keep in mind, unit tests are not very helpful if you don't have good code coverage.

As a starter, specifically for PHP development, [PHPUnit](http://phpunit.de/) is a great choice.

While it may be a new concept to you, you will quickly find how unbelievably useful unit and integration tests can be, even in just the development phase. There is actually an entire development methodology dedicated to that concept, called [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development). I would just read up on some of these concepts, come up with a coverage plan (what and where you want to test), and then try writing a couple yourself.